# Extra whitespace between HTML elements in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, whitespace

UPDATE [4th May, 2015] : It seems the latest versions of Chrome (42.*) have fixed it.

It looks like an embarrassingly simple problem, but I don't know the solution to it. One of the smallest samples which reproduces this is the following HTML code:

```
<html><body><input type="button" value="button1"/><input type="text"><input type="button" value="button2"/></body></html>
```

Please note that there is no newline or a whitespace character used anywhere in the above (except to separate the attributes)

In Firefox, it looks like this:

[image]

But like this in Chrome:

[image]

Notice the extra whitespace Chrome decides to add by itself. I've tried everything I could, but haven't been able to remove this as I need no space between these elements (or may be a minimalistic value just like FF has).

Any help on how can we do that?

Thanks ...

Comment: it must be your css. the above HTML by itself is fine in chrome. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QKvLn/ so show us your css.

Comment: @kennypu http://jsfiddle.net/QKvLn/1/

Comment: There is no css whatsoever! The only thing you need in the html file is the line of code I wrote above.

Comment: @Musa ahh, i always forget about the normalized css ;)

Comment: @PiyushSoni it's because all browsers set a default padding/margin on elements. this is why using a reset css is important so the elements have equal spacing in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks @kennypu. Could you just tell me one more thing. My minimalistic HTML has only the html and body tags. Then
1) Why would this work: 

    * {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
} 

and not this : 

    html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

Also, why would setting those attributes directly in the body tag work, even after mentioning the !important flag?

Comment: * means set it to every tag. html, body will only set the padding and margin for those two, when in actually you need it on the input tags

Comment: it's considered bad practice to do * {padding: 0; margin: 0;} as it'll reset the padding/margin for ALL tags, so it can result in weird behaviors for some tags in the future. the better practice is just to reset the tags that you are using, in this case, input {padding: 0; margin: 0;} would be good enough.

Comment: @kennypu :  Aah. Now I get it. Yes, I wanted to know that mysterious element on which if I set these attributes it'll work directly. It seems my understanding of the padding and margin has not been completely correct all this time. I always thought it's set on 'containers' like div/body/span etc. tags which contain the basic elements like buttons/inputs etc. Good that the mystery is solved! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to reset the styles in your CSS.

You can add this to your default style sheet.

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

If you need a little more information on resets there is a good run down here : http://perishablepress.com/a-killer-collection-of-global-css-reset-styles/

Comment: Aah. This works. Man! Why would any browser have such a weird thing! I don't know much of CSS, but the strangest thing is that I had already tried doing a padding and margin 0 on the containing body or by adding an extra containing div element. In all respects, even if it was not applicable for the whole page, it should have respected that but it didn't. 
Now I'm confused which one to mark the answer. Probably this one as it was specific even though Daan Callaert had answered it before.

Comment: Glad that solved your problem.  All browsers handle css differently.  Some better than others.  I tend to reset styles using the above code in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your CSS, http://www.cssreset.com/. 
Some DOM elements have browser specific layout values if you don't reset them.

Comment: Thanks Daan Callaert, resetting CSS worked. Strange, I never knew such a thing existed. Though you were the first one to answer, I'd marked Brent's one as the answer as that gave the specific code block which directly fixes the problem. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Glad that I could help you for a moment !
Using a CSS reset in combination with a valid (W3C) HTML code, you can solve many cross-browser incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed adding a new line in the source often adds whitespace to select tags. This is VERY bothersome if you like readable source. Sure, you don't need a new line in the source, but it shouldn't be this way. It's a bug in Chrome.